# When to create Generic and partial class

Tags: c#, .net, class

Let's say I have 3 classes, in these classes I have 2 common function and 1 different, same with the members (some are same. some are different).
These classes object are created in `foreach` loop and in one iteration only one of the class object is created.

I'm looking for better approach for creation of class:

1. can create a base class then drive child classes
2. can create a main class, rest as a inner class
3. can create a abstract class and rest as different classes
4. can create 3 partial classes
5. can create a generic class

I just want to know the better approach, in case I can create the three partial classes or any generic class? - then please explain.

I am using C# 3.0

Comment: Generic classes and partial classes are two completely different things...

Comment: You should use partial classes only in combination with a code generator. One part is generated by some tool, the other you write yourself.

Comment: @slfan: I don't think that's the only purpose of partial classes...

Comment: @BoltClock: Of course you can use it differently, but I can't think of any good reason for it. If you have to split your class in two halves, it's probably bad designed.

Comment: Actually not ONLY. SOmtimes it makes snes to split off certain complex / large functions into a partial class. Not most of the time, but sometimes.

Comment: @BoltClock, why I am thinking of generic class is that so that I can pass the type of the class to some base generic class. and for partial - I'll create three classes with same name. i.e what I am thinking

Comment: @Nits: with partial classes you create one class splitted up into three files. They have to be in the same assembly.

Comment: Sounds like you want one abstract base class then three classes that inherit it, each with its own set of new properties and methods. Can't see any real need for partial class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. can create a base class then drive child classes**

Good candidate. However, look at 3. below. If you have classes `Employee` and `Manager` where `Manager` derives from `Employee` you should use this solution. `Employee` is not abstract.

**2. can create a main class, rest as a inner class**

Bad candidate. Inner classes is simply a way to scope classes. Most of the time you should avoid public inner classes, and then inner classes simply becomes an implementation detail of your class.

**3. can create a abstract class and rest as different classes**

Good candidate. Same as 1. except your base class cannot be instantiated. If your base class is "incomplete" and need to be derived to be fully specified you should choose this solution. If your classes are `Employee`, `SalariedEmployee` and `ExternalEmployee` where `Employee` is the base class this solution is right. An employee is not correctly described unless you know if the employee is salaried or external.

**4. can create 3 partial classes**

Bad candidate. A partial class is a way to split the source code of your class into several source files.

**5. can create a generic class**

Probably a bad candidate. Generic classes are used to create a single (generic) class that implements the same behavior with varying type parameter. You describe that your classes have different methods, and a generic class does not have "different methods" depending on the type parameter.

Comment: i am going ahead with abstract class and will making function which I need to implement in child classes as abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Partial Class - allows you to produce **one** class that is implemented in multiple files within the same assembly. As slfan pointed out, this is very useful when part of the class is being generated and part is hand written.

Generic Class - allows you to produce **one** class that has a single implementation that works a specific way, but does not care what it works on. The perfect example of a this is a List. List doesn't care what is actually in the list, but it knows how to get the first element or remove the third.

Abstract Class - allows you to produce **multiple** sub classes of the **single** abstract class. The abstract class depends on the subclasses to implement some of the methods. This differs from a generic class because an abstract class knows something needs to happen, but it does not know what that something actually is, the subclass knows.